# How to reset available apps (what macOS sees as viable options) and test if they're are present options in 10.15.x Catalina?

Tags: applications, catalina, launch-services

I'm having some odd issues where, after moving to Catalina, some applications are not now being seen. This especially holds true for some (*awesome*) [Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) apps.  I've had some LSD crashes that mention database seeding problems as well that cause me to have to do an entire reboot.

To this end I used [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) to rebuild the LaunchServices database:

[image: onyx]

Unfortunately this has not yielded any improvements in seeing the apps that I'm expecting to see.

Is there a more comprehensive way to rebuild the LSD properly and then to make queries to it in order to test to see if the expected apps are available again to / through it?